# Update with state change triggering GetMouseButtonDown

Tags: unity-game-engine, mouseevent, state

I'm struggling to find an elegant solution to what seems to be a fairly simple problem.

In `Update()` some code executes in **state1**, and when `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` is clicked, some more code is executed and the state is changed to **state2**.

However, state2 also has a `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` which is being triggered by the original `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` from state1 as the change happens quickly, as `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` can return true for several frames.

I've tried using booleans, and using `Time.deltaTime()` but I'm having issues with ensuring that the first mouse click doesn't trigger the second.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is edge detection. Essentially you check a condition for a change in state. While the boolean is the same as the last time you asked it you don't do anything but once it changes you execute some code.

```
//global variable
bool lastState = false;

//inside a method
bool newState = Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
if(newState != lastState)
{
    lastState = newState;

    //do stuff
}
```